# Printf blocked by for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, printf

I'm an armature programmer, and I wrote a code to calculate the time taken by a for statement to execute. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long long int i;
    int a,b;
    struct timeval st,end;

    printf("\nEnter two numbers to multiply");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("\nOh, wait! I have to count upto 4294967295 before i multiply");
    gettimeofday(&st,NULL);
    for(i=1;i<4294967295;i++);
        printf("count : %lld",i);
    gettimeofday(&end,NULL);
    printf("Time elapsed: %lu:%lu\n",end.tv_sec-st.tv_sec,end.tv_usec-st.tv_usec);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The for loop takes ~13 seconds to finish. However the printf statement is executed only after for loop completes execution. Why is this happeneing.

Comment: "Oh, wait! I have to count upto 4294967295 before i multiply" - That's weird :)

Comment: Do you indeed multiply `a` and `b` somewhere?

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun This is a part of code where I was trying to demonstrate the usefulness of threads. Multiiplication has to wait for 9 seconds before it actually happens in this code. But if I use threads, multiplication gives instant result while the counting continues in background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard output stream is not always directly flushed (i.e. written to your screen),

try

```
fflush(stdout);
```

just after the line you want printed.

Answer (score 6):

Remove `;` from the end of `for` loop.

```
 for(i=1;i<4294967295;i++);  
                          ↑ Remove this semicolon.
```

It should be

```
 for(i=1;i<4294967295;i++)
 {
      printf("count : %lld",i);
 }
```

Comment: Indeed. It's like writing `for(i=1;i<4294967295;i++) { }`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun; OK, tell me how you did that? I tried many times by using unicode 2191 but getting weird output.

Comment: That's a secret in my family for generations, can't tell you.. sorry.

Comment: @MarounMaroun; OK... OK you Iron Man , I will reveal your secret.

Comment: To be honest, I think that the empty for-loop is intended behaviour.

Comment: for(...); and for(...){...} is same i guess, so it didn't work.